# What is happening while I'm sitting at the load screen?

Tags: league-of-legends

When loading into a game sometimes it takes a real long time due to just one player. Often you hear the "toaster" jokes once everyone gets in game referring to the assumed poor quality hardware of the slow loader. I always assumed the long loading times had more to do with network latency than their actual hardware. But that's just because I have no idea what's happening in that time frame. So is the wait time actually because someone had a slow computer, or is it because they had slow internet?

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate for GameDev.SE either, this particular SE feels more appropriate since it's more about the gaming from a user perspective.

Comment: I don't think anyone but the developer of LoL can correctly answer your question, so its probably not a good fit for any SE. The message about maybe trying on gamedev is a default one.

Comment: @Arperum For a specific answer that's probably true, but panomosh's answer below does a good job of narrowing it down. Perhaps I can rephrase it to be less about the implementation.

Comment: Since the question is locked, I'll answer it here. Load time hugely depends on the speed of your hard drive, as well as amount of RAM you have (anything above 3gb shouldn't make much of a difference). Speed of CPU makes a difference as well, but switching from HDD to SSD will reduce the load times immensely and the internet connection doesn't make any difference in load times whatsoever even in multiplayer games like LoL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is loading the map and game settings into memory ready for the game. I'd imagine it will also be downloading information about the other players.

From personal experience though I can tell you that the speed you load a LoL game at depends A LOT more on your hardware.

I have been in a game with my friend on a 2MB line whilst he was on a 10MB line.

He was on a laptop and I was on my Gaming rig and I was still ready a lot faster than him, even though I was connecting to the internet via a solar powered calculator in the dark.

Comment: If you go out in an offensive way to ask why you got a downvote, you're only going to get more. Also [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) regarding downvotes.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Well, it's not a question is it.

Comment: It is an answer, and I believe a correct one. He just isn't sure of himself. 
He even has evidence about how it's not related to network latency and related to hardware.

Comment: @Panomosh I've edited your question a bit to help it out [see here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/172811/revisions) . If you don't like my edit, or feel like you can improve it further - please edit it further. Don't be discouraged by downvoters - they are trying to help you improve your answer. People on this site don't generally like uncertainty in answers, find some evidence for your claim and that will certainly help.